# Championed their way to the top

Tags: grammar

Let's say Ryu is now hailed to be the best street fighter overall. Can you say:

> It is not M.Bison or the others who is the strongest, it is Ryu who has **championed** his way **to the top**.

This *champion* thing followed by '*to the top*' does make me feel unease, coz it sounds redundant. Is it repetitive or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordinarily the verb "to champion" has a somewhat different meaning:

> **[champion](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/champion)** (v): *3. to act as militant supporter of : uphold, advocate*

but I really don't see much wrong with your version.  It's not uncommon to *verbify* a noun to make a particular point, so much so that it's likely the origin of some common figurative verbs like "to shoulder" or "to muscle".  Example:

> That guy has been **eyeballing** me from across the room all evening.  It's kind of creepy.